# Why does installing likewise-open uninstall openssh-server?

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-10.10, likewise-open

So I'm just toying around with LikeWise, but I noticed that when I installed it, it decided to uninstall openssh-server. Nothing serious since I assume that I can reinstall it, but why would it uninstall in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a really tough question, probably the only way to know would be to run `apt-get install likewise-open openssh-server` and see what apt is tripping over when you tell it you want both of them.  Are you actually running Maverick? (Installed fresh or `apt-get dist-upgrade` from a previous version)  If you just updated apt's sources but never actually upgraded everything, then installing likewise-open might have pulled in a kerberos or openssl library that an older openssh-server wasn't compatible with, in which case installing openssh-server again would get Maverick's openssh-server.

This is one of the things I like about the front ends (`dselect` was great about this)... they usually explain WHY the choice you made has this outcome.